# Emails associated with labels

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have created a label and put some mails in that label from Inbox. Later I have tried to change the name and found at the bottom of the page something that says "Removing a label will not remove the messages with that label."

So I have removed the label to create a new one. But fortunately I don't find the mails which I have put for that label.

So my question is where does I find those mails, which I have removed the folder / Label.

Please help, where I have saved all  my decades work.

Comment: The settings section that is called "labels" lets you rename the labels. However, if renaming the label does not satisfy your needs, you should search based on the original label and add the second (new) label to those. Then you could remove the original (old) label.

Answer (score 1):

Every email has a label, at least when it is first created, received or ingested. A email before it is sent is a *draft*, one that has been received has the *inbox* label, one you sent has the *sent* label.

When you archive a message the inbox label is removed. Any other label it has remains with the message. When you removed the label from the messages, the messages were not deleted, they still exist, they just no longer have that label attached to them.

You will have to search for messages without a user created label, using the advanced search tools. Or if you have some other way of identifying them such as key words, subject, or recipients, or some other label.